# In Blackberry Display Labelfield as Link

Tags: blackberry

How to display the labelfield text as link and it should be clickable.for example i have the text Forgot Password that text should be display as link.and clicking on that it should goto another screen.

please give some suggestions or usefull links.bcoz iam new to the developing blackberry applications.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following custom control for that.

```
package com.myapp.controls;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.Color;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Font;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Graphics; 

public class HrefField extends Field {

private String content;
private Font fieldFont;
private int fieldWidth;
private int fieldHeight;
private boolean active = false;
private int backgroundColour = Color.WHITE;
private int textColour = Color.BLACK;
private int[] drawFocusColors;

public HrefField(String content) {
    super(Field.FOCUSABLE);
    this.content = content;
    fieldFont = Font.getDefaultFont();
    fieldWidth = fieldFont.getAdvance(content) + 2;
    fieldHeight = fieldFont.getHeight() + 3;
    drawFocusColors = new int[] { Color.Orange,
            Color.Orange, Color.RED,
            Color.RED};
}

public void setColours(int backgroundColour, int textColour) {
    this.backgroundColour = backgroundColour;
    this.textColour = textColour;
    invalidate();
}

public void setBackgroundColour(int backgroundColour) {
    this.backgroundColour = backgroundColour;
    invalidate();
}

public void setTextColour(int textColour) {
    this.textColour = textColour;
    invalidate();
}

public void setMaskColour() {
    invalidate();
}

public void setFont(Font fieldFont) {
    this.fieldFont = fieldFont;
}

public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return fieldWidth;
}

public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return fieldHeight;
}

protected void layout(int arg0, int arg1) {
    setExtent(getPreferredWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
}

protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int[] X_PTS = new int[] { 0, fieldWidth, fieldWidth, 0 };
    int[] Y_PTS = { 0, 0, fieldHeight, fieldHeight };
    if (active) {
        graphics.drawShadedFilledPath(X_PTS, Y_PTS, null, drawFocusColors,
                null);
    } else {
        graphics.setColor(backgroundColour);
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, fieldWidth, fieldHeight);
    }

    graphics.setColor(textColour);
    graphics.setFont(fieldFont);
    graphics.drawText(content, 1, 1);
    graphics.drawLine(1, fieldHeight - 2, fieldWidth - 2, fieldHeight - 2);
}

protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    fieldChangeNotify(1);
    return true;
}

protected void onFocus(int direction) {
    active = true;
    invalidate();
}

protected void onUnfocus() {
    active = false;
    invalidate();
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a non editable [`ActiveRichTextField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ActiveRichTextField.html).